# How can I check if a date is the same day as datetime.today()?

Tags: python

This condition always evaluates to `True` even if it's the same day because it is comparing time.

```
from datetime import datetime

# ...

if date_num_posts < datetime.today():
```

How can I check if a date is the same day as `datetime.today()`?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

If you want to just compare dates,

```
yourdatetime.date() < datetime.today().date()
```

Or, obviously,

```
yourdatetime.date() == datetime.today().date()
```

If you want to check that they're *the same* date.

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) is usually helpful. It is also usually the first google result for `python thing_i_have_a_question_about`. Unless your question is about a function/module named "snake".

Basically, the `datetime` module has three types for storing a point in time:

- `date` for year, month, day of month
- `time` for hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds, time zone info
- `datetime` combines date and time. It has the methods `date()` and `time()` to get the corresponding `date` and `time` objects, and there's a handy `combine` function to combine `date` and `time` into a `datetime`.

Comment: "It is also usually the first google result for python thing_i_have_a_question_about" And unless somebody made SO entry on this topic, like it happened here :)

Comment: You can also write `datetime.date.today()` for today's date that is similar to `datetime.today().date()`.

Answer (score 51):

- If you need to compare only day of month value than you can use the following code:

  ```
  if yourdate.day == datetime.today().day:
      # do something
  ```
- If you need to check that the difference between two dates is acceptable then you can use
  [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta):

  ```
  if (datetime.today() - yourdate).days == 0:
      #do something
  ```
- And if you want to compare date part only than you can simply use:

  ```
  from datetime import datetime, date
  if yourdatetime.date() < datetime.today().date()
      # do something
  ```

Note that timedelta has the following format:

```
datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
```

So you are able to check diff in days, seconds, msec, minutes and so on depending on what you really need:

```
from datetime import datetime
if (datetime.today() - yourdate).days == 0:
    #do something
```

In your case when you need to check that two dates are exactly the same you can use timedelta(0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
if (datetime.today() - yourdate) == timedelta(0):
    #do something
```

Comment: `.day` is the day-of-the-month. So August 12 is "equal" to December 12 using your first snippet of code. That's probably not the behavior the OP wants.

Comment: @trutheality - yep, i started to write my answer before question has been edited, so i was not able to understand what he exactly need, that is why i provide several options for this

Comment: Quick note: datetime objects have an attribute called 'day' (no 's') and timedelta objects have an attribute called 'days' (with an 's') in case people find themselves befuddled with why their syntax isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the hours, minutes, seconds and microseconds to whatever you like

```
datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

but trutheality's answer is probably best when they are all to be zero and you can just compare the `.date()`s of the times

Maybe it is faster though if you have to compare hundreds of datetimes because you only need to do the `replace()` once vs hundreds of calls to `date()`

Comment: I'd vote for this if it didn't involve mutation. You can however adapt this method by creating a clone of the datetime objects you're comparing, then modify them by removing fields with sub-day resolution, then compare the copies.

Comment: @ninja, it doesn't mutate. replace() returns a new datetime object, like str.replace() does

Answer (score 2):

```
all(getattr(someTime,x)==getattr(today(),x) for x in ['year','month','day'])
```

One should compare using `.date()`, but I leave this method as an example in case one wanted to, for example, compare things by month or by minute, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to convert the date in strings and compare them.

```
from datetime import datetime

today= datetime.today()

if today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == other_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
    print("same day as today: {0}".format(today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

Comment: down-voted for not comparing data but datas shapes. There is a way to compare data, see trutheality's answer