# Pandas: How to detect the peak points (outliers) in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, outliers

I am having a pandas dataframe with several of speed values which is continuously moving values, but its a sensor data, so we often get the errors in the middle at some points the moving average seems to be not helping also, so what methods can I use to remove these outliers or peak points from the data?

Example:

```
data points = {0.5,0.5,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.6,4,0.5,0.5,4,5,6,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9}
```

in this data If I see the points 4, 4, 5, 6 are completely outlier values,
before I have used the rolling mean with 5 min of window frame to smooth these values but still I am getting these type of a lot of blip points, which I want to remove, can any one suggest me any technique to get rid of these points.

I have an image which is more clear view of data:
[image]

if you see here how the data is showing some outlier points which I have to remove?
any Idea whats the possible way to get rid of these points?

Comment: You could calculate the z-score of all points and reject above some threshold.

Comment: @ALollz that works in the case when your normal distribution lies on both sides, but here I won't have any value below zero, or speed will never go in negative, still Is the right technique to use the z-score in this case ...???

Comment: Oh good point, that data will not be normal. Do you have a sense of what the underlying distribution should be empirically?

Comment: Here’s a link that may be of use: [outlier detection on skewed distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129274/outlier-detection-on-skewed-distributions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really think z-score using [scipy.stats.zscore()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) is the way to go here. Have a look at the related issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904088/deleting-the-same-outliers-in-two-timeseries/50906623#50906623). There they are focusing on which method to use *before* removing potential outliers. As I see it, your challenge is a bit simpler, since judging by the data provided, it would be pretty straight forward to identify potential outliers without having to transform the data. Below is a code snippet that does just that. Just remember though, that what does and does not look like outliers will depend entirely on your dataset. And after removing *some* outliers, what has not looked like an outlier before, suddenly will do so now. Have a look:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# your data (as a list)
data = [0.5,0.5,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.6,4,0.5,0.5,4,5,6,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9]

# initial plot
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df1.columns = ['data']
df1.plot(style = 'o')

# Function to identify and remove outliers
def outliers(df, level):

    # 1. temporary dataframe
    df = df1.copy(deep = True)

    # 2. Select a level for a Z-score to identify and remove outliers
    df_Z = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < level).all(axis=1)]
    ix_keep = df_Z.index

    # 3. Subset the raw dataframe with the indexes you'd like to keep
    df_keep = df.loc[ix_keep]

    return(df_keep)
```

**Originial data:**

[image]

**Test run 1 : Z-score = 4:**

[image]

As you can see, no data has been removed because the level was set too high.

**Test run 2 : Z-score = 2:**

[image]

Now we're getting somewhere. Two outliers have been removed, but there is still some dubious data left.

**Test run 3 : Z-score = 1.2:**

[image]

This is looking really good. The remaining data now seems to be a bit more evenly distributed than before. But now the data point highlighted by the original datapoint is starting to look a bit like a potential outlier. So where to stop? That's going to be entirely up to you!

**EDIT: Here's the whole thing for an easy copy&paste:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# your data (as a list)
data = [0.5,0.5,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.6,4,0.5,0.5,4,5,6,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9]

# initial plot
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df1.columns = ['data']
df1.plot(style = 'o')

# Function to identify and remove outliers
def outliers(df, level):

    # 1. temporary dataframe
    df = df1.copy(deep = True)

    # 2. Select a level for a Z-score to identify and remove outliers
    df_Z = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < level).all(axis=1)]
    ix_keep = df_Z.index

    # 3. Subset the raw dataframe with the indexes you'd like to keep
    df_keep = df.loc[ix_keep]

    return(df_keep)

# remove outliers
level = 1.2
print("df_clean = outliers(df = df1, level = " + str(level)+')')
df_clean = outliers(df = df1, level = level)

# final plot
df_clean.plot(style = 'o')
```

Comment: @id101112 Did this solve your problems? Let me know if now and I'll have a look at it again.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I did worked on zscore approach, but i worked in some different way, Thank you so much for your kind reply

Answer (score 1):

You might cut values above a certain quantile as follows:

```
import numpy as np
clean_data=np.array(data_points)[(data_points<=np.percentile(data_points, 95))]
```

In pandas you would use `df.quantile`, you can find it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

Or you may use the Q3+1.5*IQR approach to eliminate the outliers, like you would do through a boxplot

Comment: i used these both techniques before that seems to not be working with my data, that's why I am still trying to figure out what would be the other good technique to take out only those highest points. I used z-score and also used the IQR method to get rid of these points.