# Removing datetime.datetime dates from a list of dates

Tags: python-3.x, list, datetime

I have a list of dates being returned from a table:

```
pre_dates = [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0)]
```

As you can see, they are in the format `datetime.datetime(YYYY, M, DD, H, M)`. I basically want to get rid of all the items that are `datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0)` from the list. The individual dates actually equate to `9999-09-09 00:00:00` so I keep trying the following, but it always throws a `syntax error: invalid syntax` on my `if` statement. What's the problem here?

```
 for date in pre_dates:
     if date = 9999-09-09 00:00:00:
         pre_dates.remove(date)

     # also tried if date = datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0):
     # same error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do equality comparisons on dates like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407362/how-can-i-check-if-a-date-is-the-same-day-as-datetime-today).

```
toRemove = datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0)
for date in pre_dates:
    if (date == toRemove):
        pre_dates.remove(date)
```

However, This is a somewhat expensive operation because `remove` runs in O(n), as seen [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). I would use a list comprehension like this:

```
goodDates = [d for d in pre_dates if d != datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: I really like this second method with the list comprehension. I was seeing that using the loop with `pre_dates.remove(date)`, when I ran `print(pre_dates)`,  there were still unwanted items in the list. Not sure why, but your method overcomes that issue. Thanks.

Comment: @gwydion93 No problem. List comprehensions are Python's LINQ :)

Answer (score 2):

1) Use `==` not `=`

2) You can directly compare it with the `datetime` object

```
 for date in pre_dates:
     if date == datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0):
         pre_dates.remove(date)
```

Comment: OK, it runs now. Oddly though, the item doesn't get removed from the list. Why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

```
for date in copy(pre_dates):
 if date == datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 9, 0, 0):
     pre_dates.remove(date)
```

this addresses 3 problems.

- You shouldn't iterate over a list and edit it at the same time.
- You used = instead of ==
- you compared wrong types initially